# Get value from a dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
index=  {(V, NP): VP, ('the',): Det, ('shot',): V, (V, NP, Det, Nom): VP, (Det, Nom): NP, ('Harry',): PropN, (N,): Nom, (P, VP): PP, ('dog',): N, (V,): VP, (V, S): VP, ('thinks',): V, ('Mary',): PropN, ('eager',): Adj, (NP, VP, Conj, Clause): Clause, ('gave',): V, (NP, VP): RelClause, ('give',): V, ('to',): P, (V, Adj, PP): VP, ('is',): V, ('cat',): N, (Clause,): S, ('easy',): Adj, (Adj, Nom): Nom, ('my',): Det, ('flower',): N, (V, NP, PP): VP, ('i',): PropN, (V, NP, Whw, RelClause): VP, (V, Adj): VP, ('policeman',): N, ('please',): V, ('a',): Det, ('pajamas',): N, ('This',): PropN, ('very',): Adj, ('John',): PropN, ('that',): Whw, ('said',): V, (PropN,): NP, ('pis',): V, ('chased',): V, ('apple',): N, (P, NP): PP, ('I',): PropN, ('elephant',): N, (VP, NP): RelClause, ('book',): N, ('an',): Det, ('heavy',): Adj, ('teacher',): N, ('persuaded',): V}
```

If i try to get the value by:

index.get('(V, NP)')

It returns nothing. How can i retrieve an value?

*ps: i have tried almost all the combinations to get something from the dictionary.*

Comment: The elements from tuples (keys) are strings?

Comment: Well, are V and NP variables?

Comment: What are `V`, `NP`, `Det`, `Nom`, and all those other things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your key is a tuple of variables and not a string. You have to use the same key to retrieve the value, e.g.

```
>>>index = {(1,2):3}

>>>index['(1,2)']# this will fail
KeyError: '(1,2)'

>>>index[(1,2)]
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `index.get((V, NP))`, not `index.get('(V, NP)')`

Answer (score 0):

You should try `index.get(('V', 'NP'))` or `index.get((V, NP))` (depends of whether the tuples' items are strings or variables) instead of `index.get('(V, NP)')`.